# Unloading dll's from SIlverlights App Domain

Tags: silverlight, dll, mef

Is it possible to unload a Dll that I previously dynamically loaded into my App?

Background/comments:

1.- We have a requirement that third party developers will implement a wizard-like activity that will be dynamically loaded and executed into our Silverlight application.

2.- We will probably use MEF to put the XAP and Dll catalog into the Silverlight App Domain.

3.- With MEF, its possible to unload the catalog objects, but the Dll will remain loaded into the App Domain.

What we are looking for is to get rid of those Dlls in memory, as the appliance that runs the SL application can remain powered on for long time, and we don't want to pollute its memory with unnecessary Dlls.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant unload a single dll from an appdomain on any version of th clr, the only option for unloading dlls is unloading the entire appdomain.

Unfortunatly you cant create your own appdomains in silverlight as far as i know, but you could always have multiple silverlight apps on the same page.

i wonder though if its a long running app, if its not better to look at desktop .net.. you could use the .xbap deployment format if you still want to run your app in the browser

Comment: Well, SL + IIS (or a lighter web service) is a unchangeable requirement from management, so we are blocked in that direction. As for having multiple apps, that could be a solution, Im just not sure how could we include the third party control (2nd SL app) inside the existing UI (1st SL app), as a UserControl...

Comment: You could split your app into multiple areas and have the main are just be html, that way you can put anything there.. ofcourse your scenario might not allow that :) i'd really look at if you need the unloading at all though, a web page is only going to be active for so long anyway.. i say put the unloading onhold until you can verify that its a problem.